# Pros and Cons of declaring expression in java? "sum += i" instead of "sum = sum + i"

Tags: java, for-loop

I got this question in an interview that what's the impacts of declaring expression `sum+=i;` or `sum = sum+i;` inside the loop.

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        sum = sum + i; //Expression 1
        sum += i;  //Expression 2
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're asking about the impacts in terms of what--the result? If so, it's twice as much as if there were only one accumulation operation. As an aside, these aren't "declaring expressions", they're assignment expressions.

Comment: There is no inpact,however they are different on cpu level. more on this : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice

Comment: In this case, not in java...

Answer (score 4):

In this example, there is no difference whatsoever other than what you consider easiest to read.